# Why Android's AndroidTestCase class returns getcontext as null

Tags: android, ant, junit

I am using AndroidTestCase class where i need to get context. (I am using parent project for which i am writing testcase). 
I have tried with getting context from mocktext and setting it through setup.also tried by using internal getTestContext() but nothing is working.

If any one is having idea then please let me know.

Kind Regards,
Sog

Answer (score 0):

getContext of AndroidTestCase will return the context you've set with setContext.
if you want to mock a context you probably want to extend MockContext or use some mock library and pass that mock to the class under test.
If you're trying to test an activity of a service you'd probably want to use ActivityUnitTestCase or SerivceTestCase. then you might need to to use setContext, setActivityContext or setApplication to mock the context or application of the activity or service under test.